# Extend available keys for custom key bindings in Terminal.app on MacOS

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, emacs, readline

Why are there only a few keys available which you can bind to the modifier key combinations (alt+cmd or shift+control etc) in the Terminal.app settings? For example I would like to bind a key combination like Option-Shift+E. But there are only the F1-F12 keys, the cursors and few other keys available... Is it possible to make all keys available for combinations with the "modifiers"?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant use other keys than those available in the combo, but if you want to try [iTerm](https://www.iterm2.com) wich is an alternative to Terminal.app it will let you to that.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I don't want to use any third party emulators (I've used iTerm2 before and know that you have some more options there). So the key question is not how to bind any key combinations but how to do it in Terminal.app and if it's not possible to find out why it's not possible.